# copy a audio file to server in php

Tags: php, copy

I am uploding a mp3 file from remote server to url and inserting the related to database. data is insert correctly but the copy function did not working.   i am using below code.

the file did not copy from source to destination folder.

```
if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{  
    $rand=rand(0,2000);
    $title=$_POST["title"];
    $category=$_POST["category"];
    $desc=$_POST["obj_desc"];


    //front
    $size320=$_FILES["size320"]["name"];
    $size320_dest="ringtone/music/".$rand.$size320;
    //$size320_action=copy($_FILES["size320"]["tmp_name"],$size320_dest);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["size320"]["tmp_name"],$size320_dest);




    //select data for checking

    $query_image="insert into ringtone (title,  category, detail, ring) values
        ('$title', '$category', '$desc', '$size320_dest')";              
    mysql_query("$query_image") or die ("$query_image");


}
```

Comment: Make sure the error reporting is ON and the save path is valid

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.